# Setting my 2nd monitor resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, screen, monitor, display-resolution

how do i set a custom resolution on my second monitor? I have Nvidia graphics card. I tried this

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

But that returns this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  45
Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Can you set ANY resolutions for the 2nd monitor using the Displays panel in System Settings? Click once on the image of the second display to enable appropriate choices in resolution down below. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a modeline, for example with **cvt**? Because this kind of error is usually present if you have not.

An example here:

```
cvt 800 600 60
```

(width, height, refreshrate)

An example output:

```
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

You will get something different since you are using different numbers there, but then just copy the information after the word **Modeline** and replace it in the command you tried before

Like I do here

```
xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607   624 -hsync +vsync
```

And then finally (added that DVI-I-0)

```
    xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 800x600_60.00
```

And everything should work!

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution